# Media Query Issues | DW21.3 | Missing Breakpoints

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Morning all

I've employed media query breakpoints in order for my site to be responsive as is required in the modern age. For some reason, one of my breakpoints has just disappeared in the HTML document despite my CSS covering all breakpoints up to

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px)
```

I can also confirm that my CSS document is in the root folder, situated as follows:

```html
<head>
<link href="../styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
```

I've no third-party plugins installed on DW, but I do have Google Translate and Font Awesome.

Not aware as to the media query version but is the version which came with the software.

I appreciate this is specifically a coding site, not a DW-orientated forum so if it is something to do with DW glitching out, please disregard this post. However, if you feel there is an error in my coding, let us know!

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qDKC.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OYjk.png)

Not specifically coding-oriented but tried reinstalling DW, reverting back to previous versions of the software in order to rule out any DW-related problems.

I have removed the Google Translate plugin as well as the Font Awesome plugin to see if this WAS interfering with Media Query.

Comment: Best practice is to keep all @media *in* the css file(s), not in the `<link>` in the html. If anyone changes the browser view (less or more width), the layout has to be ok in all circumstances.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I just clicked on the arrow with the plus on the ruler in the top of the HTML documents, and assigned a min-max attribute to the existing style sheet, for anybody who also comes across this issue.